# Query changed to pass field as parameter and no longer works

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure where I used to write in the field directly, but I changed it to allow the user to provide the field as TEXT:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `leaderboard_get_data`(numPerPage INTEGER,
pageNumber INTEGER, daysSince INTEGER, field TEXT)
BEGIN
DECLARE numBefore INTEGER DEFAULT (((pageNumber - 1) * numPerPage));
SET @dateSince = DATE_SUB(DATE(NOW()), INTERVAL daysSince DAY);
SELECT
    @curRank := @curRank + 1 AS PlayerRank,
        PlayerName, field 
    FROM players p, (SELECT @curRank := (((pageNumber - 1) * numPerPage))) r
WHERE @curRank BETWEEN (((pageNumber - 1) * numPerPage)) AND (((pageNumber - 1) * numPerPage) + 1) + (numPerPage - 1) - 1
AND PlayerLastGameCompletedDate IS NOT NULL AND (daysSince < 0 or DATE(PlayerLastGameCompletedDate) BETWEEN DATE(@dateSince) AND DATE(NOW()))
ORDER BY field DESC
LIMIT numBefore, numPerPage;
END
```

As you can see, field is TEXT. Now when I execute this stored proceedure, MySQL C++ Connector throws an exception with sqlstate = 0, sqlerror = 0.

I suspect I might not be passing the field correctly, there might be a special way to pass it in.

What might be wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean to specify a column, then you have to use dynamic sql (prepared statements).

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `leaderboard_get_data`(numPerPage INTEGER,
pageNumber INTEGER, daysSince INTEGER, field TEXT)
BEGIN
DECLARE numBefore INTEGER DEFAULT (((pageNumber - 1) * numPerPage));
SET @dateSince = DATE_SUB(DATE(NOW()), INTERVAL daysSince DAY);
SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT
    @curRank := @curRank + 1 AS PlayerRank,
        PlayerName, ', field, '  
    FROM players p, (SELECT @curRank := (((pageNumber - 1) * numPerPage))) r
WHERE @curRank BETWEEN (((pageNumber - 1) * numPerPage)) AND (((pageNumber - 1) * numPerPage) + 1) + (numPerPage - 1) - 1
AND PlayerLastGameCompletedDate IS NOT NULL AND (daysSince < 0 or DATE(PlayerLastGameCompletedDate) BETWEEN DATE(@dateSince) AND DATE(NOW()))
ORDER BY ', field, ' DESC
LIMIT ?, ?;');
PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt USING numBefore, numPerPage;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
END
```

Comment: Even with modofying what you gave correctly I still get the same issue.

Comment: Then please explain the problem in more detail and include the exact error messages.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it so easy. Now your `SELECT` is looking for fields named "PlayerName" and "field" in your players table. As a workaround you can try build your query into a string with `concat()` and run it as prepared statement.